# Can't add Action manager to Delphi 10.3.3 unit

Tags: delphi

I'm using Delphi 10.3.3.  Today, I added a TActionManager to a form containing a TCheckList and set a few actions.
When I tried to compile, the IDE insisted on adding IDETheme.ActnCtrls to my Uses list, then failed to compile because it couldn't find the file.
I've been using Delphi since Borland Pascal, and this one is new to me.
What can I do?  I've tried deleting, building instead of compiling, starting a new unit, a new project, restarting the IDE and starting a new project.

John Treder

Comment: Please provide the exact error message you're getting, instead of just summarizing it.

Comment: The `ActnCtrls` unit is in the `Vcl` unit scope, not the `IDETheme` unit scope. So whatever is causing it to prefix with `IDETheme` is wrong.  Change it to `Vcl`, or remove the prefix altogether and make sure `Vcl` is listed in the Unit Scope Names config in the project options

Comment: Ken White:  The error message is
[dcc32 Fatal Error] Unit1.pas(7): F2613 Unit 'IDETheme.ActnCtrls' not found.
Failed
Elapsed time: 00:00:42.2

Comment: @Remy: Vcl is indeed in the Unit Scope Names list.
When I change "IDETheme.ActnCtrls" to "Vcl.ActnCtrls", the IDE just adds the bad one back in.  Here is the uses list from my test app that has a main form, a Checklist and an Action Manager.  
uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ActnCtrls, System.Actions, Vcl.ActnList,
  Vcl.ActnMan, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.CheckLst, IDETheme.ActnCtrls;

Comment: @J.Tred: You should [edit] your question to add details, rather than putting them in comments.

Comment: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-27035

Comment: @Ken White:  Ok, Thanks,  I hadn't noticed that in the hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Known issue in 10.3.3:

[RSP-27035: [dcc32 Fatal Error] F2613 Unit 'IDETheme.ActnCtrls' not found.](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-27035)

Marco Cantu said:

> Unfortunately there is a an incorrect dependency in the IDE. If you close the file unit from the IDE, and remove that uses statement with another editor, it should compile (from the IDE) and work correctly. We are looking into a solution

Patrick Premartin said:

> il you add an empty unit named IDETheme.ActnCtrls to the project, you probably can compile without changing source file outside Delphi

A patch was released for the issue:

[#30903: RAD Studio 10.3.3 IDE and VCL Patch](https://cc.embarcadero.com/item/30903)